# fetch name from facebook and display in listview

Tags: android

I am very much new to android development. I am working on a project, in that I need to connect to `facebook` and retrieve some details
On click of Import contact button, it should :

1. login to facebook
2. retrive name , profile pic,birthdate,email
3. display all those in multi choice Listview 
   4.get all selected contact from Listview

please help me to how to get start of these things. If you provide some link for beginners or  sample code , it will be very much helpful

Comment: Please read the docs and use google its free. Try from your end when you are stuck with something get back here with a specific problem. 
Guess you can get started here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the Facebook docs, here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: I already gone through those documents , I am sorry to say I can't understand those..... Please suggest me other one which can help from the basics